# setHour without change on Time Zone

Tags: node.js, timezone, momentjs

I am coding a code on node.js which I need to set hour, minutes, seconds to now date without change time zone. (I get time from client which it sends time in hh:mm:ss format by UTC timezone)

My code on set time is:

```
  var now = new Date();

  console.log(now);
  now.setHours(format.h);
  now.setMinutes(format.m);
  now.setSeconds(format.s);
```

the now time is:

```
2016-12-30T13:30:17.586Z
```

and format is:

```
13:29:29
```

when I set seconds, the result is

```
2016-12-30T18:29:29.345Z
```

It seems the time zone is changing; How can I set hour without timezone change?

- **UPDATE**

I installed the momentjs and here is my code:

```
  var now = moment();
  console.log("before: " + now.format());
  now.add(format.h, 'hours');
  now.add(format.m, 'minutes');
  now.add(format.s, 'seconds');
  console.log("after: " + now.format());
```

here is logs:

```
format time= 3:45:38
before: 2017-01-06T12:55:45+03:30
after: 2017-01-06T16:41:23+03:30
```

Actually the time should be `2017-01-06T15:45:38+00:00`

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397226/sethour-without-change-on-time-zone/41397636#41397636) below help you? If so then you can consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

For any complex date/time manipulation it's better to use `moment`:

```
moment().set('hour', 13);
```

It will save you a lot of headaches.

See: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
date.setHours()
date.setMinutes()
date.setSeconds()
```

Use

```
date.setUTCHours()
date.setUTCMinutes()
date.setUTCSeconds()
```

And everything will work as expected :)